# What is CCARRAY_FOREACH in coccos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I see a macro CCARRAY_FOREACH in coccos2d, actually what does it? can we do alternative
solution instead of it?i am using following code for spriteBatchNode?

```
     CCARRAY_FOREACH([spriteBatch children], sprite)
{

    ...................
}
```

Comment: related , http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/ccarray_foreach/

Comment: ssteinberg's answer is correct. please update it

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is actually wrong. `CCARRAY_FOREACH` isn't a macro for fast enumeration, it is a replacement for fast enumeration for `CCArray`s. `CCARRAY_FOREACH` is a tiny bit faster than fast enumeration on a `NS(Mutable)Array` (about 10%), so better use it if you are using `CCArray`s. 
Check the `CCArray.h` header to see what the macro actually is.

Answer (score 0):

it is a macro for looping through each object inside a CCArray... an alternative would be objective-c's foreach `for (object in array)` that goes like this:

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in [spriteBatch children]) {
    ...
}
```

this is for NSArray and NSMutableArray but i think it should work fine for CCArray as well.