# nsmutablearray not adding objects when called

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, null, nsmutablearray, scheduler

I have an NSMutable array that I want to add Sprites to so that I can check them if they've hit the wall. I use this code to do so:

```
NSString *bulletName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tank%d_bullet.png", _type];
bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:bulletName];
bullet.tag = _type;
bullet.position = ccpAdd(self.position, ccpMult(_shootVector, _turret.contentSize.height));        
CCMoveBy * move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:duration position:actualVector];
CCCallBlockN * call = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}];

if (!bulletIsGone) {
    [self schedule:@selector(updator:) interval:0.01];

}
else {
    [self unschedule:@selector(updator:)];
}
[bullet runAction:[CCSequence actions:move, call, nil]];
[_layer.batchNode addChild:bullet];
[bulletsArray addObject:bullet];
if ([bulletsArray objectAtIndex:0] == nil) {
    NSLog(@"HELP");
}
NSLog(@"%@", [bulletsArray objectAtIndex:0]);


}

-(void)updator: (ccTime) dt{

for(CCSprite *bulletz in bulletsArray){
    NSLog(@"this is the for loop");
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(bulletz.position.x - bulletz.contentSize.width/2, bulletz.position.y - bulletz.contentSize.height/2, 20, 20);
    if ([_layer isWallAtRect:rect1]) {
        NSLog(@"bulletHitWall");
        [_layer.batchNode removeChild:bulletz cleanup:NO];
        bulletIsGone = YES;
    }
}

}
```

However, when I build and run, I get the console output of '(null)' and 'HELP.' The method before the 'updator' is called from touchesEnded. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to add bullets to another array? You already have a batch node that contains them all which is `_layer.children`.

Are you sure that the array itself (`bulletsArray`) is not nil? where is it initialized?

Finally you should consider looping with [CCARRAY_FOREACH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872855/what-is-ccarray-foreach-in-coccos2d) which is more performant.

Answer (score 3):

Do you initialise the array? That would seem like the most likely reason

Try this in your viewDidLoad method...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  bulletsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `NSMutableArray` cannot hold `nil` objects, the only way the condition

```
[bulletsArray objectAtIndex:0] == nil
```

could evaluate to `true` is that `bulletsArray` is `nil`. You need to make sure that the array is properly allocated. A typical place to do it is the designated initializer of your class.